# Демо данные для wordpress шаблона Newses

Tags: php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование, данные

В Wordpress репозитории есть шаблон Newses. Как можно посмотреть демо данные для него? Откуда их можно скопировать?

Answer (score 1):

На странице темы в репозитории WordPress есть ссылка Theme page. Пройдя по ней, попадаете на страницу темы: https://themeansar.com/free-themes/newses/.

Там надо кликнуть большую чёрную кнопку Demo Data.